# Duplicating 8-bit BMP with C++

Tags: c++, image

Trying to create a simple image processing library in pure C++. Here is the first part, duplicating 8-bit BMP images (taken from Udemy in hybrid c/c++ but I modified it a bit). Any comments are welcome.

#### `Image.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>



class Image
{
public:
    Image(const char *filename);
    ~Image();

    void CopyTo(const char *filename) const;

private:
    int _width;
    int _height;
    int _depth;
    unsigned char *_header;
    unsigned char *_table;
    unsigned char *_buffer;
};
```

#### `Image.cpp`

```
#include "Image.hpp"

Image::Image(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fi = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (fi == nullptr)
    {
        printf("%s", "Unable to open the file");
        exit(1);
    }

    _header = new unsigned char[54];
    fread(_header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fi);

    memcpy(&_width, _header + 18, 4);
    memcpy(&_height, _header + 22, 4);
    memcpy(&_depth, _header + 28, 2);

    if (_depth <= 8)
    {
        _table = new unsigned char[1024];
        fread(_table, sizeof(unsigned char), 1024, fi);
    }

    _buffer = new unsigned char[_width * _height];
    fread(_buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), _width * _height, fi);

    fclose(fi);
}

Image::~Image()
{
    delete _header;
    delete _table;
    delete _buffer;
}

void Image::CopyTo(const char *filename) const
{
    FILE *fo = fopen(filename, "wb");

    fwrite(_header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fo);

    if (_depth <= 8)
        fwrite(_table, sizeof(unsigned char), 1024, fo);

    fwrite(_buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), _width * _height, fo);

    fclose(fo);
}
```

#### `test.cpp`

```
#include "Image.hpp"



const string array[] =
{
        "flower",    // 0
        "car",       // 1
        "robot",     // 2
        "computer",  // 3
        "baby",      // 4
};

const int selector = 4;
const string pi = (string)getenv("RESOURCES") + "/" + array[selector] + ".bmp";
const string po = (string)getenv("RESOURCES") + "/" + array[selector] + "_copy.bmp";

int main()
{
    Image m(pi.c_str());
    m.CopyTo(po.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question doesn't take in to account the palette which comes before pixel data. It ends up reading the palette in to pixel data.

8-bit, 4-bit, and 1-bit bitmaps have palettes. The palette starts immediately after file header, and before image data.

Width alignment is not considered. The width of the bitmap, in bytes, should always be aligned to 4. For example, for 8-bit bitmap, if the width of the bitmap is 311, it should be padded in memory and in file, so it reaches 312. The display will still show only 311 pixels in width.

Support for big/little endian can be added.

`std::vector<uint8_t>` instead of user allocated buffer will simplify memory management.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Image
{
    template<typename T>
    void readint(std::ifstream& f, T& val)
    {   //endian-independant read
        //static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 4); //requires c++17
        uint8_t buf[4];
        f.read((char*)buf, sizeof(val));
        val = 0;
        for (int i = sizeof(val) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            val += (buf[i] << (8 * i));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void writeint(std::ofstream& f, T val)
    {   //endian-independant write
        //static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 4); //requires c++17
        uint8_t buf[4];
        for (int i = sizeof(val) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            buf[i] = (val >> 8 * i) & 0xff;
        f.write((char*)buf, sizeof(val));
    }

    //based on BITMAPFILEHEADER, struct size will be off
    struct cfileheader
    {
        char type[2];
        uint32_t size;
        uint32_t reserved;
        uint32_t offset;
    };

    //based on BITMAPINFOHEADER, struct size will be off
    struct cinfoheader
    {
        uint32_t struct_size;
        uint32_t width;
        uint32_t height;
        uint16_t planes;
        uint16_t bitcount;
        uint32_t compression;
        uint32_t image_size;
        uint32_t xpermeter;
        uint32_t ypermeter;
        uint32_t colors_used;
        uint32_t colors_important;
    };

    Image(const Image&) {} //lets make these inaccessible
    Image& operator = (Image const&) {}
public:
    Image();
    bool readfile(const char* filename);
    bool writefile(const char* filename);
    bool isopen;
    int  width, height;
    int  width_in_bytes;
    int  bitcount;
    cfileheader fileheader;
    cinfoheader info;
    std::vector<uint32_t> palette;
    std::vector<uint8_t> image;
    uint32_t getpixel(int x, int y)
    {
        switch (bitcount)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            const int rowindex = (height - y - 1) * width_in_bytes;
            const uint8_t bit = (image[rowindex + x / 8] >> (7 - (x % 8))) & 1;
            return palette[bit];
        }
        case 4:
        {
            const int start = (height - y - 1) * width_in_bytes;
            uint8_t pal = image[start + x / 2];
            if (!(x % 2)) pal >>= 4;
            return palette[pal & 0xf];
        }
        case 8:
        {
            //find the index of pixel at x/y
            //the pixel should have a value between 0 to 256
            //get the color from palette
            const int i = (height - y - 1)* width_in_bytes + x;
            const uint8_t pal = image[i];
            return palette[pal];
        }
        case 24:
        {
            const int i = (height - y - 1) * width_in_bytes + x * 3;
            return image[i + 2] + (image[i + 1] << 8) + (image[i + 0] << 16);
        }
        case 32:
        {
            const int i = (height - y - 1) * width_in_bytes + x * 4;
            return image[i + 2] + (image[i + 1] << 8) + (image[i + 0] << 16);
        }
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

Image::Image():
    isopen{ false }, fileheader{}, info{}, 
    bitcount{}, width{}, height{}, width_in_bytes{}
{
}

bool Image::readfile(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream fin(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!fin) { std::cout << "open failed " << filename << '\n'; return false; }
    
    fin.read(fileheader.type, 2);
    if (strncmp(fileheader.type, "BM", 2) != 0) return false;
    readint(fin, fileheader.size);
    readint(fin, fileheader.reserved);
    readint(fin, fileheader.offset);

    readint(fin, info.struct_size);
    readint(fin, info.width);
    readint(fin, info.height);
    readint(fin, info.planes);
    readint(fin, info.bitcount);
    readint(fin, info.compression);
    readint(fin, info.image_size);
    readint(fin, info.xpermeter);
    readint(fin, info.ypermeter);
    readint(fin, info.colors_used);
    readint(fin, info.colors_important);

    width = info.width;
    height = info.height;
    bitcount = info.bitcount;

    if (info.struct_size != 40)
    {
        printf("wrong structure size %d\n", info.struct_size);
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<uint16_t> bitcheck {1,4,8,24,32};
    if(std::find(bitcheck.begin(), bitcheck.end(), bitcount) == bitcheck.end())
    {
        printf("cannot handle this bitcount %d\n", bitcount);
        return false;
    }

    int palette_size = (bitcount > 8) ? 0 : (1 << bitcount);
    palette.resize(palette_size);
    for (auto &e : palette)
    {
        //BGRA -> ABGR
        uint8_t buf[4] {};
        fin.read((char*)buf, 4);
        e = buf[2] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[0] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
    }

    if(fin.tellg() != fileheader.offset)
    { printf("error reading image\n"); return false; }

    width_in_bytes = ((width * info.bitcount + 31) / 32) * 4;
    image.resize(width_in_bytes * height);
    fin.read((char*)image.data(), image.size());
    isopen = true;
    return true;
}

bool Image::writefile(const char* filename)
{
    if (!isopen) return false;
    std::ofstream fout(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!fout) { std::cout << "open failed " << filename << '\n'; return false; }

    fout.write((char*)fileheader.type, 2);
    writeint(fout, fileheader.size);
    writeint(fout, fileheader.reserved);
    writeint(fout, fileheader.offset);
    writeint(fout, info.struct_size);
    writeint(fout, info.width);
    writeint(fout, info.height);
    writeint(fout, info.planes);
    writeint(fout, info.bitcount);
    writeint(fout, info.compression);
    writeint(fout, info.image_size);
    writeint(fout, info.xpermeter);
    writeint(fout, info.ypermeter);
    writeint(fout, info.colors_used);
    writeint(fout, info.colors_important);

    for (auto &e : palette)
    {
        //ABGR -> BGRA
        uint8_t buf[4]{};
        buf[0] = (e >> 16) & 0xff;
        buf[1] = (e >>  8) & 0xff;
        buf[2] = (e >>  0) & 0xff;
        buf[3] = (e >> 24) & 0xff;
        fout.write((char*)buf, 4);
    }

    fout.write((char*)image.data(), image.size());

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

If image is opened successfully, we access to `image` (these are the pixels on the screen), `palette` if any, plus basic information such as width, height, and bit count.

For example, `img.image[index]` is the pixel at that index, it has matching color based on `img.palette`

See `getpixel` function for more detail.

```
Image img;
img.readfile("bitmap8bit.bmp");
if (img.isopen)
    for (int row = 0; row < img.height; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < img.width; col++)
        {
            //drawpixel(row, col, img.getpixel(col, row)); ?
        }
```

Reading 8-bit bitmap is easier than modifying it. To edit 8-bit, we may need to modify the palette color and rebuild the color palette, this code will not do that.

Note that bitmap file header is always 14 bytes. The bitmap header is usually 40, but not always. This code assumes 40, otherwise it reports failure.

Answer (score 2):

`const char *filename`
Why does it require a C-style string?  Use the `std::filesystem::path` type.
More generally for strings that are not filenames, parameters should be `std::string_view` to be efficient for passing `std::string` as well as a lexical string literal without having to copy it.

---

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

`if (fi == nullptr)`
Don't make explicit comparisons against the null pointer.  Use the truth value of the pointer (which may be a smart pointer!) itself.  Here, `if (!fi)`.
But, why are you using `FILE*` things, instead of C++ library features?

Meanwhile, you don't need `FILE` in the header, so move the `#include` to the implementation file.

Do you really want to exit the program?  If you use this class in a real program, you may prefer to go back to the menu or prompt for the filename again, rather than exiting!   You should throw an exception here, which gives the caller the possibility of dealing with it.

---

`_header = new unsigned char[54];`
Why does this need to be on the heap??  Just put the 54-byte array in the class directly.

---

`_buffer = new unsigned char[_width * _height];`

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

Use `unique_ptr`.  This will make freeing automatic and you don't need to write the destructor at all. It will also make sure you don't leak memory if an exception is thrown (see above).

---

The `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so you don't need to state that.

---

`const string array[] =`
How does that compile?  You are not including the right header nor `using std::string;` anywhere.

## but why?

You're partially parsing the contents of a particular type of file, but in the end just copy the whole file.  Why not just copy the file itself, without caring what's in it?

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy You can change the settings on Intellisense.  I use VSCode myself.  I mainly turn off "change what I actually typed" because it's annoying and fights me on things, but keep what I like such as brace pairing and auto change indenting for opening/closing braces.  Look for the settings with `Clang_format` as part of the name.